# Get top level folders only using Python Box SDK

Tags: python, box-api, boxsdk

I am trying to run a search query in Box root folder to find folder names that contain a particular string. However I only want the folders that are 1 level below (similar to a `ls` command). However `get_items()` will return folders matching the string even deeper down.
For example if I search for `"AA"` in the below folder structure it should only return `Folder1AA`, `Folder2AA` and `Folder3AA` and **not** `Folder4AA` and `Folder5AA` :

```
StartingFolder
Folder1AA
    File1B
    Folder4AA
        Folder1C
            File1D
Folder2AA
    Folder5AA
        File1C
    Folder2B
        File1D
Folder3AA
    File1B
```

Any ideas on how to do that ?